# Fragment container with Viewpager, tabs, and drawerlayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a drawerlayout, viewpager, and tablayout in my `activity_main.xml` I have two fragments `HomeFragment` and `BookingFragment`, I'm trying to launch the `BookingFragment` from another activity's on itemclick. I have tried multiple solutions like creating a framelayout with the id `container` and put the pager inside it and then user it in the fragment transaction and also I tried making an empty framelayout with the same id and put it above the pager, but it didn't work.

Here's the code for my method that I'm trying to start the fragment from

```
public void startTransaction(){
        Fragment newFragment = new BookingFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.pager, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Here's my `activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="net.app.cairobus.cairobus.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
            android:background="#fff" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#f2f2f2"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/accent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/secondary_text"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and here's the fragment I'm trying to start

```
public class BookingFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static BookingFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BookingFragment fragment = new BookingFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BookingFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }


    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booking, container, false);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't programmatically add a `Fragment` to a `ViewPager`.  That's the job of the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

So your main activity has a HomeFragment tab and a BookingFragment tab.  You want to navigate from the HomeFragment to a TripActivity, and then navigate from the TripActivity to the BookingFragment.

To navigate from the HomeFragment to the TripActivity, use `Activity.startActivityForResult()`.

To navigate from the TripActivity back to the BookingFragment, call `Activity.setResult()` then `Activity.finish()`.  In `setResult()`, you can set a result code that means "open the BookingFragment" and set any other parameters you need in the data intent.

In your MainActivity, override `onActivityResult()`.  When you receive a result code for the BookingFragment, call `setCurrentItem(page)` on the `ViewPager` to display the BookingFragment.

If you need to set up fields in the BookingFragment, you'll need to keep a reference to the BookingFragment returned from `adapter.getItem()` so you can call setters, etc.

Comment: And by doing that it would launch the fragment and kill the current activity I am inside?

Comment: If you need to switch the activity, then you would start the activity with the `ViewPager`, then in `onCreate()` call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(page)`.  You could control which fragment you display by setting a parameter in the intent for the page to set as current item.

Comment: `ViewPager` works with the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to manage the fragments inside the `ViewPager`.  When you add a fragment directly to a `ViewPager`, you are messing up the `ViewPager`'s internal housekeeping.

Comment: The "Activity" that I am currently inside is not a fragment, it's just a regular activity, what I am trying to accomplish is launch a "fragment" from inside my activity and pass some data to that fragment using Bundle. How can that be accomplished without using FragmentTransaction, exactly?

Comment: I'm confused about the navigation.  Is the activity you're launching from the main activity with the tabs & view pager?  Does the BookingFragment need to be swipeable therefore inside a ViewPager?  If you want the fragment to be swipeable, then you would have a ViewPager and the BookingFragment would be set from the FragmentPagerAdapter.  If you don't want the fragment to be swipeable, then you would have a container like a FrameLayout and do the FragmentTransaction like you have.  But you can't combine FragmentTransactions with ViewPagers.  The adapter does the transactions internally.

Comment: The navigation is like this, I have a main activity in which I implement the viewpager, the view pages shows two swipeable fragments they are called Home and Booking. The user does some interaction in home fragment and then on a button click it takes him to an activity called "trips activity", and notice that it's an activity not a fragment. Now the user will choose something and on the click of a button it should take him to the booking fragment. That's what I am aiming for. Home fragments starts by default when the view pager starts, I want to be able to launch booking from an activity.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I updated my answer based on your explanation.